# Finagle Resolver not found for scheme

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I create my own finagle resolver, and I want to test it in my scalaTest. But since my test does not provide the META-INF/services/com.twitter.finagle.Resolver file, when I run the client

```
  Http.client.newService("myResolver!foo.com:/endpoint", "service")
```

I receive the error

```
com.twitter.finagle.ResolverNotFoundException: Resolver not found for scheme "myResolver". Please add the jar containing this resolver to your classpath
```

Any idea how to test a resolver in my test running with Intellij?

Comment: You have answered your own question: "since my test does not provide the META-INF/services/com.twitter.finagle.Resolver file ..." Make it provide the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing the META-INF file to intellij, like Dima suggested?